# How can I scroll the outer ListBox when my cursor is in a nested ListBox?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

So the DataTemplate for the items displayed in my ListBox also uses a ListBox. But whenever my cursor is within one of those nested ListBoxes I can no longer scroll at all. I dont want the nested Listboxes to scroll, only the most outer ListBox.

I tried to set CanContentScroll to false for the ListBoxes in the template but it didnt change anything.

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="TestelementTemplate">
            <Expander Margin="0" Background="{StaticResource Green200Brush}"Padding="0">
                <Expander.HeaderTemplate>
                    ...
                </Expander.HeaderTemplate>
                <StackPanel>
                    <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding ChildElements, Mode=OneWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" ItemTemplate="{DynamicResource ResourceKey=TestelementTemplate}" ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="False" BorderThickness="0" Padding="0" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" Visibility="{Binding HasTestelements}" />
                    <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding ChildTasks, Mode=OneWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ResourceKey=TaskTemplate}" ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="False" BorderThickness="0" Padding="0" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" Visibility="{Binding HasTasks}"/>
                    <Separator/>
                </StackPanel>
            </Expander>
        </DataTemplate>
```

Comment: Nested ListBoxes seems like such an ugly way to handle this hierarchical data display - try using a TreeView control instead.

Comment: If you don't want them to scroll then have you considered itemscontrols instead of listboxes?

Comment: @Peregrine i completely agree but the treeview control is not fit for my needs in this instance.

Comment: @Andy thank you! works perfect and looks better too!